# using angular reactive forms the defaults values i was setting in ngOnInIt are not getting reflected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When i was loading default values in ngOnInit in angular, using angular reactive forms the defaults values i was setting in ngOnInIt are not getting reflected. I'm using `filter` within the map

Based on URL I need the value in the map needs to be selected by default in the dropdown. Any help is appreciated.

```
tMap = [
  { url:"test", Name:'rony' },
  { url:"cool", Name:'rocky' }
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm.controls['hub'].setValue('rony');
  this.url = (window.location.href).substring(22,26);

  const selectedHub: { url:string, Name: string } = 
    this.tMap.filter(ele => ele.url == this.url)[0];
  this.loginForm.controls['hub'].setValue(selectedHub.Name);
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div>
   <select formControlName="hub" ng-model="hub" id="login" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"
      style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px; background-color: white; font-weight: 600">
      <option *ngFor="let h of tMap"><a [href]="h.url">{{h.Name}}</a></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and the initialization of your form controls

Comment: Hi @batajus added the html code. please help to checkat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `[value]` in your select option:

```html
<option *ngFor="let h of tMap" [value]="h.Name">
  <a [href]="h.url">{{ h.Name }}</a>
</option>
```

With that, Angular now knows what to bind to. Also, remove `ng-model` from `select`, first of all it is AngularJS syntax, secondly you are already using the formcontrol, so no need to use `[(ngModel)]` (which is the Angular syntax).

Comment: Plus, why would he add `ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched` explicitly...? Something's not right with that HTML

Comment: Oh, did not even notice that, you are correct, that is strange.